# How to count by a field of a nested entity?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework

Every time a user views the News page, the time of the view is saved in the `LastTimeNewsPageWasViewed` property of the `User` entity.

I want to count how many new news were posted since the last time the user viewed the news page.

My problem is that i don't know how a proper statement for this should look like in Entity Framework.

The following code doesn't work. But how could be archived something like this?

```
var totalCountOfNewNewsNotYetViewedByCurrentUser = context.Subscriptions
                 .Where(s => s.TvShow.News.CreatedOnDate > currentUser.LastTimeNewsPageWasViewed)
                 .Count();
```

Comment: @JeroenVannevel I had a problem. Solved it. And posted it here in case anyone else will run into the same problem?

Comment: Right I got that, it's just that it's very unclear what your actual problem was and what the solution to it was. Can you expand?

Comment: @JeroenVannevel is it better now or do you think that it's still too unclear? I will try to expand it even more if it's still unclear.

Comment: Thanks, that's a much better question already. Can you also expand on the answer to explain how this solves it? For future reference: always make sure to tell us what isn't working specifically. E.g.: you get different results, you get no results, you get an error, etc.

Comment: @JeroenVannevel added some comments in the code of my answer. Hope that helps, don't know how else to describe it more in detail. :(

Answer (score 1):

I ended up using this:

```
if (currentUser == null)
{
    return 0;
}

// Here we create all "custom objects with custom properties (NewNotificationsTotalCount)" for each tv show.
var anonymousObjects = context.Subscriptions
     .Where(s2 => s2.UserId == currentUser.Id && ((s2.TvShow.IsPrivate == false) || (s2.TvShow.IsPrivate == true && s2.UserId == currentUser.Id)))
     .Select(s => new
     {
         NewNotificationsTotalCount = s.TvShow.News.Where(n => n.CreatedOnDatetime > currentUser.LastTimeViewedSubscriptions).Count()
     });

var newNotificationsTotalCount = 0;

// Now we must go through all the anonymous objects we created before and sum together all new news for all tv shows else we would just get the count of new news for only one tv show (if we used something like anonymousObjects.FirstOrDefault() for example).
foreach (var oneAnonymousObject in anonymousObjects)
{
    newNotificationsTotalCount = newNotificationsTotalCount + oneAnonymousObject.NewNotificationsTotalCount;
}

return newNotificationsTotalCount;
```